# understand inkscape bezier flattening algorithm

Tags: javascript, python, svg, bezier, inkscape

Hello I'm working translating svg to hpgl format. and the plotter i use understand only the first version of hpgl that doesn't understand bezier curves. so i'm trying to convert the inkscape function that flattens the curves to line segment from python to javascript.
There are 4 files that i'm reading and i'm kind of lost in all the math stuff.
in the [hpgle_encode.py](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/blob/master/share/extensions/hpgl_encoder.py) there is a call to fucntion named [cspsubdiv](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/blob/master/share/extensions/cspsubdiv.py) i think it stands for cubic super path sub division and from what i understood it is a recursive call that split every bezier cuvre in two (with De Casteljau's Algorithm) until the number of polyline is flat enough. this is determined by the distanceToPoint found in the [ffgeom](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/blob/master/share/extensions/ffgeom.py). What i don't understand is what c1 and c2 stand for and what mathematical concept are behind distance calculation of distance. also i don't understand the recursive part of the subdiv function. i could't debug the inkscape extension so i couldn't see what sp [i] represented in:

```
def subdiv(sp,flat,i=1):
    while i < len(sp):
        p0 = sp[i-1][1]
        p1 = sp[i-1][2]
        p2 = sp[i][0]
        p3 = sp[i][1]

        b = (p0,p1,p2,p3)
        m = maxdist(b)
        if m <= flat:
            i += 1
        else:
            one, two = beziersplitatt(b,0.5)
            sp[i-1][2] = one[1]
            sp[i][0] = two[2]
            p = [one[2],one[3],two[1]]
            sp[i:1] = [p]
```

Comment: c1 and c2 where? Your code doesn't have variables with that name.

Comment: You might find it useful to read one of the articles on bezier flattening on the web. [For example this one](http://antigrain.com/research/adaptive_bezier/).

Comment: c1 and c2 are in the ffgeom library line 82 in the link.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau i real a lot about bezier flattening but i want to use insckape particular algorithm cause i'm pleased with the curve precision when i printed to to hpgl with inkscape. but i can't underrstand what c1 and p1 means as they a re not very talkative names and without a debugger it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dot()` function, in the code you linked to, is calculating the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two vectors.

The dot product calculates the "scalar projection", or how much one vector projects along the length of another vector.

[image: Scalar projection using dot product]

So if you have a line segment approximating a section of curve, and the bezier control points for that same section of curve, it should be fairly obvious how helpful this would be in calculating how close this line segment comes to approximating the curve.

The closer the control points are to the line segment, the more accurate the line segment is. When it gets to a predetermined closeness, you no longer need to use deCasteljau to split the curve into two smaller segments.